# Different lighting on duplicate projects...weird

Tags: lighting

This project is duplicated, but it doesn't have the same lightning. I have tried everything almost…I am going crazy :( Please help!

Project files: https://easyupload.io/m/53jzah

Here is a render between the projects.

https://imgur.com/a/DFMPh1v

it is quite hard to see if you don’t save the images and then go back and forth between them.

Another one, images of rendered asteroids
: https://imgur.com/a/DQG6tBL

And one more , images of Ceres: https://imgur.com/a/EG1OrEb

What I have checked:

- Light paths
- world shader
- compositor
- subdivisions
- motion blur
- color management
- camera, clip start - end
- sizes of light
- noise treshold
- samples
- material
- textures

Comment: Hello, you haven't shared the images (the HDRI for example), also you link to images but you don't show any comparison

Comment: Hi :). The particle system seems to have a bit different distribution in each file. That could cause these changes.

Comment: The sun's _Emission Strength_ in the first file changes from 8 at frame 249 to 2 at frame 287, while in the second it goes from 0 at frame 274 to 8 at frame 781, so at least the files are not exactly lit the same. In the first file the start/end are 0 to 2555, so the sun is a while at 8 but most the time at 2. In the second the range is 2360 to 4190, which means in that animation the strength is 8 all the time.

Comment: @moonboots, I have shared the images with comparison in opening post.

Comment: @jachym michal How can the particle system be different, when they are exactly the same?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann - However they are exactly the same from 0 and the other project from frame 838. Nothing else matters. Only frame 0 and frame 838.

Comment: @robeloto Yeah sorry, but which frames matter is not stated in the question and it is not obvious from the files. If I would hit Ctrl+F12 on both files to render the animations in the given frame ranges, they would have changing lights over the rendered frame ranges.

Comment: Its an animation and the seam stops at 838 and starts from frame 1 in other project and I cannot connect the 2 projects because blender sucks ass. No one can fix this. I knew it already so.

Comment: Check your Sun material Emission strength - the animation value is altered. Key frames are different. What you could do is pick your favorite version and import and assign  the desired animations from the other version.  Or simply start over with your animation.

Comment: @Rumenbelev , I know it is altered. However on frame 838 and on frame 0 in the other project they are exactly the same. Emission strength 8. We are talking about 2 single images here with same values, but still differs somehow. I say it is a blender bug. It is frustrating when people doesnt seem to understand my problem.